# How can I replace GRUB with Windows 10 bootloader?

Tags: grub2

My machine has Windows 10 Pro installed alongside Ubuntu 15.10. As I installed Ubuntu after Windows, GRUB 2 is the default boot loader. I am sorry, Ubuntu fans, but GRUB is "pure ugly".

I tried BURG, but it is not so great too. I want to know if there is any way to replace BURG with Windows bootloader (Note: I want to be able to boot into Ubuntu from Windows bootloader).

**Additional information: My PC is an old machine, it does not use UEFI, just classic MBR.**

Comment: By ugly, are you talking about looks, or functionality?

If the former, I don't see much need in replacing BURG/GRUB with the Windows 10 boot loader.  This kind of change could result in your Ubuntu partition being hidden/not bootable.

Comment: Windows ignores anything that is not Windows... So it does not see Ubuntu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Important pre-information :** This is valid for older machines with *Legacy BIOS* and addresses this information of the question -> 
**My PC is an old machine, it does not use UEFI, just classic MBR.**

Boot the Ubuntu system ... open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo mount /dev/sdYY /mnt
sudo dd if=/dev/sdXX of=/mnt/linux.bin bs=512 count=1
```

Note : XX = Ubuntu partition | YY = Windows 10 partition
To identify the disks and partitions you can use **GParted**.

Boot from a Windows 10 DVD or USB installation media.
On the 'Install now' screen select Repair your computer.
Choose the option Command prompt and then execute :

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootrec.exe /fixboot  
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

Shutdown and boot into the Windows operating system.
Open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
bcdedit /create /d Ubuntu /application bootsector  
bcdedit /set {***} device partition=c:  
bcdedit /set {***} path \linux.bin
```

Note : *** = identifier of the new entry in the BCD store
Now you have an Ubuntu entry in Windows´ boot menu.

Comment: I just tried to do this, and on the first command got an error from dd: `dd: unrecognized operand ‘linux.bin’`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can acheive both by using a tool called EasyBCD:

http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

Also, here is a link to a nice step-by-step detailing the process of adding a Linux option in the Windows Boot Loader:

http://linuxbsdos.com/2012/03/10/restore-the-windows-bootloader-to-mbr-after-dual-booting-with-linux/

Comment: Note EasyBCD is a paid only solution, currently US$30